# How to pass scope to directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to make a custom directive that makes decisions based on the model that is being passed. I followed an example that looks a lot like what I want to do, [here](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/).

In the end, I pass a JSON address to the directive using this code snippet:

```
<div><b>Address</b>
    <address-source address="company.address"/>
</div>
```

This is the directive:

```
AppDirectives.directive('addressSource', function ($compile) {
  var template = '<span> {{address.id}} </span>';

  var getTemplate = function(scope) {
    console.log("address id: " + scope.address.id);
    return template;
  };

  var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.html(getTemplate(scope)).show();

    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
  };

  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    link: linker,
    scope: { 
      address: '='
    }
  };
});
```

The address is in scope, and the `{{ address.id }}` is resolved. However, when I want to do calculations with it, like logging it to the console, an error shows up that scope.address is undefined. What am I doing wrong? I see no differences with the working example.

Comment: Can you reproduce it here? http://plnkr.co/edit/wR67opQB2EAI62rdHMv0?p=preview

Comment: As a matter of fact I can not. I think it is basically the same as I have above, but it works there. Even when I reset the versions to those that I am using, Angular 1.0.7 and jQuery 1.11.1

Answer (score 0):

> when I want to do calculations with it, like logging it to the console

Where are you doing those calculations? If it is not in the `linker` function then you won't have access to the address as it lives in the isolated scope you requested when you wrote:

```
scope: { 
  address: '='
}
```

Comment: As you can see above, I am passing the scopefrom the linker to the getTemplate function and logging it there, unsuccessfully.

Comment: oh yes, sorry I missed that. In which case my explanation is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Remove .show() From this.

```
element.html(getTemplate(scope)).show();
```

Like:

```
element.html(getTemplate(scope));
```

SEE [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmC5W/2/)